# Javascript error when embedding Amazon Recommendation Javascript Widget

Tags: javascript, typeerror, amazon-advertising-api

I try to embed an amazon recommendation widget on my site but I get the following error in the console and the widget display with and empty box:

```
dynscript-1.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at Object.d.addEventHandler (dynscript-1.js:1)
    at Object.e.trackFormSubmission (dynscript-1.js:1)
    at Object.e.renderSearchBar (dynscript-1.js:1)
    at Object.e.render (dynscript-1.js:1)
    at o (dynscript-1.js:1)
    at Object.d.init (dynscript-1.js:1)
    at Object.e.init (dynscript-1.js:1)
    at dynscript-1.js:1
    at h (onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=87884aaa-94ab-4393-895a-ebfe6886f93b&storeId=xxxxxx-20:1)
    at Object.m.execBodyScripts (onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=87884aaa-94ab-4393-895a-ebfe6886f93b&storeId=xxxxxx-20:1)
```

The code in the page:

```
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US&
adInstanceId=a830e6a0-c6c1-4f0a-84ab-0e2dc445ff9d&storeId=xxxx-20"></script>
```

update: I found out that **Amazon Native shopping ad code doesn't run when you put it within a form HTML tag**, can't find a way to solve it. There are quiet a few discussions about it on [engagedforums.com](https://engagedforums.com/discussions/Amazoncom_Associates/_/My_website_cant_display_Native_Shopping_Ads_banners_Ads_display_ok/am-associhelp/48663.1?nav=messages&mobile=y), but all of them without any good solution. Some suggested putting the code in a separated html and inside an iframe, but this is a bad solution for contextual ads that rely on service relevant ads based on the content of the page.

*I replaced the original storeId id with xxxx

Comment: the error is not related to http. does the widget require any other scripts? you have no errors when widget is not included?

Comment: @SergChernata that's the only code Amazon associates provide to embed in the page. I get no errors without the widget.

Comment: is this live somewhere?

Comment: @SergChernata The problem is that the code doesn't run when it within a <form> tag for some reason. I just put in inside a plain HTML page, it works, but when inside a form tag it isn't. Can't find a way around it. I use it in an ASPX page, so a form tag is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create a dynamic `script` tag and add it to the head with javascript. That way at least you could load their resources. There still may be some errors due to loading order.

```
var amzScript = document.createElement('script');
amzScript.src = "//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=a830e6a0-c6c1-4f0a-84ab-0e2dc445ff9d&storeId=xxxx-20";
var head = document.querySelector('head');
head.appendChild(amzScript);
```

Comment: Thanks, I found a clean solution by disable the search bar functionality. Answered the question myself, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After digging around, I found out that the code will work inside a form tag if you disable the search bar functionality. But you have to use the code where you initialize the variable values yourself.

You can do it by adding this line:

```
amzn_assoc_search_bar = "false";
```